# dcjs ordinal line chart filtering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js

I am trying to create a line chart in dcjs with ordinal (string) X Axis values like this one here:

https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/ordinal-line.html

My problem is that when xUnit are dc.units.ordinal filtering is not enabled.
Is there a workaround to enable filtering in this line chart like in integer x Axis line charts?

Comment: [This issue on GitHub has a comment](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/348#issuecomment-285517407) describing how to imitate an ordinal scale using an integer scale. The issue is for bar charts but I think the same steps should work for line charts. It's a little tedious but I think it's the easiest way to get this functionality without modifying dc.js